# Scala basic for loops getting skipped and not entering the loop for execution

Tags: java, scala, for-loop, syntax, compilation

Ran into an issue in my service where any for loop placed in a Scala class just gets skipped and doesn't enter the loop for execution:

```
def createSample(){
  for (x <- 0 until 3) {
    println(x)
  }
}
```

Another example:

```
class messageTest extends FunSpec with GivenWhenThen with Matchers {

  def validatemessage(message: message, checkMessageRef: Boolean = true) = {
    assert(message.getMessageId == UserId.fromString("545n”))

    if (checkMessageRef) {
      assert(message.getMessageReferenceText == “refersnce”)
     }
  }

  val messageV5 = createmessageV5
  val testmessage = createtestMessageContextV5

  describe("message") {
    it("throws an error if message is not populated") {
      assert(
        intercept[InvalidFieldException] {
          new message(null, testmessage, "Search")
        }.getMessage == "Message Context cannot be null")
    }
    it("throws an error if MessagetestContext is not populated") {
      assert(
        intercept[InvalidFieldException] {
          new message(messageV5, null, “Fetch”)
        }.getMessage == "test Message Context cannot be null")
    }

    it("should initiate the context with testmessage when populated") {
      When("the constructor is called with valid data")
      messageV5.setUserId(“123454")
      val message = new message(messageV5, testmessage, "Search")

      Then("message is correctly populated")
      validatemessage(message, false)

    }

    it("should initiate debugTrace to accordingly to the input provided in the message") {
      val messageV5 = createmessageV5
      messageV5.setUserGUID("123454")
      When("the with a 'null' DebugTrace object")
      messageV5.setDebugTrace(null)
      Then("message debug trace is false")
      assert(!new message(messageV5, testmessage, "Search").getDebugTrace)
      When("the with a 'false' DebugTrace object")
      messageV5.setDebugTrace(false)
      Then("message debug trace is false")
      assert(!new message(messageV5, testmessage, "Search").getDebugTrace)
      When("the with a 'true' DebugTrace object")
      messageV5.setDebugTrace(true)
      Then("message debug trace is false")
      assert(new message(messageV5, testmessage, "Search").getDebugTrace)
    }

  }

  def createmessageV5: messageType = {
    val messageV5 = new messageType

    ***for (x <- 0 until 3) {
     println(x)
    }***

    messageV5.setMessageId(“545n”)

    messageV5.setMessageReference(“reference”)

    messageV5
  }
}
```

The above is just a part of the test but it works as expected, but when I just add this for loop to the class it just gets skipped, the same happens no matter what scala test I place it in.

In short when its compiled its being read as an empty statement for some reason and just skips to the next line of executable code.

Comment: I will definitely get `0 1 2`. Make sure `createSample()` is invoked from main function

Comment: Are you calling the method `createSample()` anywhere in your code ?

Comment: How do you know if code before/after the `for` is executed?

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: I've debugged the code while running the test in the scala class and every time it hits the for loop it skips over it and does not enter to execute the println

Comment: I've tried the same by just adding this simple for loop in other scala tests but every time I debug the test it reaches the for loop but never enters it

Comment: You have not posted enough code to recreate the problem. You say you've "debugged the code while running the test." Does that mean you ran it, step by step, under a debugger? Which debugger did you use and which "step" command? Where were the breakpoints placed?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on intellij and debugged the test step by step, the breakpoints were placed right before the for loop line started. Once the step reached the loop the next step will just skip to the next line of code after the loop and will not enter. 

As for recreation all I've done is added that for loop above to a scala test.

Comment: Put a `println` before the loop to prove that the function is called. Also, you are using deprecated syntax, better to use `def createSample() = {`

Comment: Right, the code I put above was just a sample since the issue occurs in general in every scala test I place the loop in. Execution does reach the for loop.

Comment: @RoshanVarghese When you say "execution does reach the for loop" are you talking about the output from the code, or what the debugger is telling you? Debuggers can get it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether this is a code issue or a debugger issue, so here are two possible scenarios:

#### Code issue

If `createSample` is not printing anything when you run it outside the debugger then it is a code issue, and running it under the debugger is just going to confuse things. Use `println` statements to trace the execution of the code and this may help show why the function is not being called. Update your question with a minimal example of failure and we will try to help fix it.

#### Debugger issue

If `createSample` prints correctly outside the debugger then this is a debugging issue. The debugger cannot "enter the loop" because [there is no loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAXtO5dMqEI) in your code, just a call to `foreach` on a `Range` object. By default IntelliJ will just step over this call unless you choose `Force Step Into`. If you do this you will eventually reach the actual loop which is in `Range.foreach` which, in turn, calls the lambda function containing your `println` statement.

If you put a breakpoint on the `println` statement the debugger should stop there.

Comment: Thanks!! It looks like it was a debugger issue and it does stop inside when I place the debug point inside, but it does create a problem as in the tests fail when it doesnt execute the code within the loop when I run the test

Answer (score 0):

Well lets try it:

```
scala> def createSample(){
     |   for (x <- 0 until 3) {
     |     println(x)
     |   }
     | }
createSample: ()Unit

scala> createSample()
0
1
2
```

Your code has no problem. So the issue is that the method is not getting called because, either:

1. You are not calling it!
2. There is an`exception` or an error of some sort, something like:

   ```
   scala> def createError(){
    |   throw new Exception("Ack Ack")
    | }
   createError: ()Unit

   scala> def pipe(){
    | createError()
    | createSample()
    | }
   pipe: Unit

   scala> pipe()
   java.lang.Exception: Ack Ack
   at .createError(<console>:8)
   at .pipe(<console>:10)
   ... 33 elided
   ```

Now because you said it is a service, I think you are calling a third-party service but not catching its errors, and so you cannot see the exception; and therefore that part of the code is not running.

Comment: Thank you, but the method was called and this is the issue I found while debugging the test on my local system..the debug step reaches the for loop as expected when we run the test but never enters the loop and skips to the next executable line, no exceptions are thrown

Comment: @RoshanVarghese Dave said that you are *calling* a third-party service. Not that you were running something locally or remotely.

There is something before the for loop that is failing silently.

David also said *"but not catching its errors, and so you cannot see the exception"*

Try to put try/catch blocks everywhere before that for loop, and just catch the most generic Exception possible, in order to debug this. Alternatively put `println("WE REACHED HERE")` everywhere before that for loop.

Comment: Right I see what you meant, but as I mentioned there were no errors or exceptions after adding try/catch to see during the test and execution did reach the for loop correctly. The only new change to the already existing test is the addition of the simple for loop. I was under the assumption that the syntax may not be correct but it looks fine.

Comment: In short when its compiled its being read as an empty statement for some reason and just skips to the next line of executable code